# How can improve csv reader & writer script performance?

Tags: python, csv

My script that reads image links from an input csv, and performs quality checks on each of those images. It will then append the data from the checks to a new csv. Obviously, doing several checks on each line will be a limiting factor, but I am trying to determine a way to speed up the processing. I thought about reading in multiple lines at one time, but would that help? What would be some suggested ways to speed this script up?

```py
# runs each check as needed
def add_to_row(row, line_num):

    # my processing checks would go here

    #appending score and check results
    for idx, i in enumerate(results):
        row.append(i)

# deals with csv file
def add_column_in_csv(input_file, output_file, transform_row):
    # open input file and create output file
    with open(input_file, 'r') as read_obj, \
        open(output_file, 'wb') as write_obj:
        # create a csv.reader object from the input file object
        csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
        # create a csv.writer object from the output file object
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # read each row of the input csv file as list
        for row in csv_reader:
            # append the headers and values from checks in add_to_row
            transform_row(row, csv_reader.line_num)
            # add the updated row to the output file
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

# let them know it is doing something
print('Analyzing input file . . .')
# actually add the data to the new csv here
add_column_in_csv(input_file, output_file, add_to_row)
# it is done
print('Done analyzing file. Output created: ' + str(output_file))
```

Comment: It’s easy to imagine that the image checks will take 99% of the processing time: what’s the point in optimising the rest of the code? Personally I wouldn’t bother messing about with multiprocessing (which adds complications and overheads) when you can get the same effect by splitting the source CSV into smaller segments of (say) 100k rows and feed each segment to it’s own python instance, running several to spread across cores.

Comment: @barny that was one option I was thinking of too. How would I go about starting down that path? Or do you mean doing it manually?

Comment: Not too hard to write some code to read the big CSV and chunk out batches of the size you choose to smaller CSV files. If you know how many cores you will run it on, maybe make this code create separate subdirectories of CSV files, one for each core?